# Animating UIView based on as-yet undetermined layout

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom view, `CustomView`, that can animate itself in response to an `animate` message:

```
// in a view controller
[self.customView animate];
```

Inside `-[CustomView animate]`, the logic is as follows:

```
- (void)animate {
    for each subview {
        startFrame = subview.frame;
        endFrame = EndFrameFromStartFrame(startFrame);
        subview.animation = AnimationLoopBetween(startFrame, endFrame);
    }
}
```

<sup>* This block is pseudocode.</sup>

That is to say, the `animate` method examines the current frame of each subview and generates an animation ending frame for each subview which is essentially a frame which is a fixed ratio larger than the current frame. Then, it creates one animation per subview that varies the frame of its subview, alternating between the current (or start) frame and the end frame, calculated earlier.

This method works very well in general. It allows `CustomView` to animate properly regardless of how its superview positions and sizes it.

However, in a few cases, "users" of `CustomView` (that is, view controllers) call `animate` very early in their lifetime – so early, in fact, that Auto Layout has not yet made any constraint or layout passes. This means that `animate` is called when all of `CustomView`'s subview frames are `CGRectZero`. As you can probably guess, this causes both the starting and ending values of the animations to be calculated incorrectly.

Even after the layout pass is complete, and the views' model layers have the proper frames, the `CustomView` instance is still not visible, because its subviews are happily animating from one zero-rect to another. Not good.

*How should I restructure this animation behavior to allow users of this class to call `animate` at any time without negative repercussions?*

---

Here are some possible answers I've considered, and why they don't seem satisfactory to me:

1. In any view controller that uses `CustomView`, put off the call to `animate` until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
   This forces an unwieldy restriction on view controllers that use this view.
2. In `CustomView`'s `layoutSubviews` method, first call `[super layoutSubviews]`, then restart the animation if it was already running.
   An interesting idea, but `CustomView` has more than one level of subviews. Thus, even after `[super layoutSubviews]`, many of the views further down the view hierarchy will not yet have valid frames, meaning `animate` will still misbehave.
3. In `CustomView`'s `layoutSubviews` method, first call `[super layoutSubviews]`, then manually layout any required views' frames using `[<view> layoutIfNeeded]`, before finally restarting the animation if it was already running.
   This might actually work, but doesn't seem like a good idea. As much as possible, I'd like to leave layout work to Auto Layout.

Comment: "As much as possible, I'd like to leave layout work to Auto Layout." But calling `super layoutSubviews` _does_ perform auto layout. That is what auto layout _is_. Putting code in `layoutSubviews` after your call to `super` is perfectly standard and correct - including, if necessary, changing the constraints and calling `super` again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just skip the uninteresting case?

```
- (void)animate {
  if (CGRectEqualToRect(self.frame, CGRectZero) return;
  // ...animate.
}
```

Comment: I'd like a view controller to be able to call `animate` whenever it chooses, including before layout has happened (e.g., in `viewDidLoad`). If I skip such calls, like this, my view will appear, but will not be animating.

Comment: Without layout, what exactly is the behaviour you expect from your animation? Or are you intending `animate` to act as a big "on" button that will begin the animation after your views have been laid out?

Comment: The latter part, yes. I'd like `animate` to just enable animation, no thought required. That is, after a call to that method, the view will animate any time it is on screen, even if the call came before layout.

Comment: Does the view's frame have any effect on the subview animations? By your earlier statements, I would guess "yes". What do you expect to happen to the animations when you change the frame from one non-zero rect to another while animating?

Comment: Good question (and yes, it does). Auto Layout will recalculate the views' model frames, but without intervention, the animation would continue without change. I suppose I'd like the view to take note, end its current animation, and the restart, with `animate` using the new current frames as starting points.